# Rails - How to access Facebook wall posts of a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am building a Rails site for a friend. It is mainly going to be a static website with a few exceptions. On the homepage I would like to display the latest Facebook wall posts from a Facebook user's profile, that way my friend can post a status update on Facebook and it will be reflected on the homepage of the website. What would be the best way to go about implementing this? Should I be using the Facebook Graph API or be looking for a Facebook Ruby gem or is there some other way of doing this? Can someone please tell me what I should use to do this task? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may look into http://facebook-ruby.sourceforge.net/ or http://rfacebook.rubyforge.org/